# Searching for a bit-string $x$ such that for $f: \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ we have $f(x) = 1$

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a function $f: \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, where for one particular value of $x \in \{0,1\}^n$ we have $f(x) = 1$ and for all other values $y \neq x$, $f(y) = 0$. Now suppose that I choose $k$ values for $ 1 \leq k \leq n$, say $x_k \in \{0,1\}^n$ and test if $f(x_k) = 1$.

If the values $k$ were not distinct, then I would imagine that the probability of not choosing $x$ is $ (\frac {2^n - 1} {2^n})^k$, whereas if the $k$ values are distinct, then the probability of not choosing $x$ is $\frac {2^n -1 }{2^n} \frac {2^n - 2 }{2^n - 1} \cdots \frac {2^n - (k-1)} {2^n - k}$.

The author of the textbook I am reading writes that "if choosing $k$ values will find $x$ with probability $1 - \epsilon$ for $0 \leq \epsilon  \leq 1$, then we must have $1 - \frac {k} {2^n} < \epsilon$". I am not sure how this was arrived at, insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is being a bit lenient in terms of accuracy. What the author is really trying to say is this:

> When choosing randomly $k$ elements among $\{0,1\}^n$, you cannot guarantee a probability to find your $x$ that is higher than $\frac{k}{2^n}$.

What the author writes, somewhat inaccurately, is this:

> If the probability that a subset of $\{0,1\}^n$ whose cardinality is $k$ contains $x$ is *larger than* $1-\epsilon$ then $1-\frac{k}{2^n}<\epsilon$.

The point is that the probability that a subset of $\{0,1\}^n$ whose cardinality is $k$ contains $x$ is equal to 
$$1-\frac{{2^n-1\choose k}}{{2^n\choose k}}=\frac{k}{2^n}$$
(because in order not to contain $x$ you must choose $k$ elements among the remaining $2^n-1$). Now, if you know that this probability is *exactly* $1-\epsilon$, then you obviously get $\epsilon=1-\frac{k}{2^n}$; however, if you want to guarantee a probability *larger than* $1-\epsilon$, then you get $\frac{k}{2^n}>1-\epsilon$, whence $1-\frac{k}{2^n}<\epsilon$.